# Excessive spaces caused by BBcode tables (PHP)

Tags: php, html-table, str-replace, bbcode, nl2br

I've done extensive Googling, and I just can't seem to figure it out. Hopefully you can help me.

I'm programming a message board. The system filters HTML out of replies, and forces my members to use standard BBcode instead.  All of the basic BBcodes are running smoothly, however I've run into a snag with my table codes.

**The BBcode**

This is the script that controls the BBcode on my message board. It's pretty simple and straight forward. I'm concerned about [table] [tr] and [td] only, but I included [b] so that you will understand that the function handles more than just the three codes I'm working with.

```
function BBcode($original_string) {

$find = array(
'/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is',
'/\[table\](.*?)\[\/table\]/is',
'/\[tr\](.*?)\[\/tr\]/is',
'/\[td\](.*?)\[\/td\]/is'
);

$replace = array(
'<b>$1</b>',
'<table border="1" cellpadding="5">$1</table>',
'<tr>$1</tr>',
'<td>$1</td>
);

$new_string = preg_replace ($find, $replace, $original_string);

return $new_string;

}
```

So if a member wanted to use table BBcode codes in their response on the message boards, they would probably type something like this:

```
[table]

[tr]
[td]Cell 1[/td]
[td]Cell 2[/td]
[td]Cell 3[/td]
[/tr]

[tr]
[td]x[/td]
[td]y[/td]
[td]z[/td]
[/tr]

[/table]
```

Which is great! This works just as planned.

**The Problem**

Though it has one major flaw – if a member submits the table using the BBcode I provided above, nl2br adds a whole bunch of useless spaces. You can see what I mean here:

[image]

(imagine how much worse it will be with each added TR)

However, if the user posts their comment like this:

```
[table] [tr] [td]Cell 1[/td] [td]Cell 2[/td] [td]Cell 3[/td] [/tr] [tr] [td]x[/td] [td]y[/td] [td]z[/td] [/tr] [/table]
```

Their posted comment looks fine:

[image]

**What I've Tried Already**

I've figured out that this is happening because I use nl2br on these comments. Currently, it adds BR tags before the BBcode function runs. I tried moving nl2br after the BBcode, but that didn't work.

Next, I went back to the BBcode function and tried to do an str_replace within the arrays.

```
function BBcode($original_string) {

$find = array(
'/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is',
'/\[table\](.*?)\[\/table\]/is',
'/\[tr\](.*?)\[\/tr\]/is',
'/\[td\](.*?)\[\/td\]/is'
);

$replace = array(
'<b>$1</b>',
'<table border="1" cellpadding="5">' .print str_replace("<br />", "", "$1"). '</table>',
'<tr>$1</tr>',
'<td>$1</td>
);

$new_string = preg_replace ($find, $replace, $original_string);

return $new_string;

}
```

I also tried to write that line countless other ways, such as:

```
'<table border="1" cellpadding="5">' .str_replace("<br />", "", "$1"). '</table>',
'<table border="1" cellpadding="5">' .str_replace("<br />", "", "$1"). '$1</table>',
'<table border="1" cellpadding="5">' .str_replace("<br />", "", "$1"). '$1</table>',
'<table border="1" cellpadding="5">' . $thing = str_replace("<br />", "", "$1"); . '$thing</table>',
'<table border="1" cellpadding="5">' . $thing = str_replace("<br />", "", "$1") . '$thing</table>',
'<table border="1" cellpadding="5">' . print str_replace("<br />", "", $1); . '</table>',
etc
```

Basically, what I want to do is replace all of the BR tags that are found in the [table] code. How do I do this? What am I doing wrong? Should I change my approach?

I apologize in advance if this question has been answered elsewhere. I saw at least three people with this same issue on other forums, but the OPs were all linked to the same place – a thread with the solution now given on an expired link. But if I missed something, please link me!

If you have any questions, please ask!

Answer (score 0):

What I did when I met this problem is hiding the `br/`

I set the table inside a custom `div`

```
$replace = array(
    '<div class="tablepost"><table border="1" cellpadding="5">' .print str_replace("<br />", "", "$1"). '</table></div>',
```

Then added this css trick :

```
.tablepost > br {
  content: ' '
}
```